# VBA, Locating first 20 rows within a range of rows located by a string. Search within search, Copy-paste

Tags: excel, vba, search, copy-paste

A source file has information about future prices of different metals (Copper, Zinc, Etc.) Their names are in Column A.

The period of the future price is in second column(B) (2020-01-01, 2020-01-31 / 2020-02-01, 2020-02-29, etc)
The date when the price for each period was published is in column (C)
The price for the period is in column E.

**Task:**

I need to find Copper within all metals. Then I need to locate the latest publish date for Copper (Ex: 22/11/2019). Then within this date, I have to locate only the first 20 closest periods of future prices (Ex:from present November till June 2021)

I've managed to locate the whole copper for the date I need (22/11/2019).
But I have a problem selecting the first 20 periods closest periods. The price I get with my code is just the last one from the Copper Rows for 22/11/2019.

I hope this picture will help with understanding the task.

So the problems is in this last step. But ff there are better alternatives to my initial logic,it would be great to hear it as well.

[image]

```
 Set elements = Workbooks(file_name & file_date & file_format).Worksheets(file_name & file_date).Range("A2:A3000")
 Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
 Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Forwards")
 Set dates_pnl = ws1.Range("A2:A21")

 For Each element In elements
    If element.Value = "Copper-LME" Then
        If element.Offset(0, 2).Value = today Then
            For Each x In dates_pnl
               x.Offset(0, 1).Value = element.Offset(0, 4).Value
            Next
        End If
    End If
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you want to approach this with VBA, you could first sort your range by publish date, descending. Then you have many options:

- filter to copper and return the price in the first row
- iterate through with a loop until you hit Copper and return the price from that row
- use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup` by the metal name field

Alternatively you can use PowerQuery to create and save a query for the latest Copper price. Then you can retrieve the M syntax for the query from Advanced Editor and pass it as string to VBA. That is a bit complex, but it can save you the fuss with opening this report.

Hope this will get you going.

Comment: I need at least to return all the prices (rows) for that on date